# validating number input regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am writing a regex for my shell script program that will check

1) the number should be 8 digit

2) the first number must start from 8 or 9

below is what I have but the regex doesn't seem to make anything happen

```
startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex="/^[8-9]/d{8}"
echo "Enter a 8 digit number"
read eightDightNumber
if [[ $eightDightNumber =~ $startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex ]]; then
   echo "Number must start with 8 or 9"
elif [[ $eightDigitNumber -lt 8 ]]
   echo "Number must be in 8 digits "
else
   echo $eightDightNumber
fi
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regular expression to `'^[89][0-9]{7}$'`.

Beside that, if statement body should be adjusted.

```
startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex='^[89][0-9]{7}$'
echo "Enter a 8 digit number"
read eightDightNumber
if [[ "$eightDightNumber" =~ $startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex ]] ; then
   echo $eightDightNumber
else
   echo "Number must start with 8 or 9 and should be in 8 digits"
fi
```

or negate the expression:

```
startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex='^[89][0-9]{7}$'
echo "Enter a 8 digit number"
read eightDightNumber
if [[ ! "$eightDightNumber" =~ $startWithEightOrNineDigitRegex ]] ; then
   echo "Number must start with 8 or 9 and should be in 8 digits"
else
   echo $eightDightNumber
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
^[89][0-9]{7}$
```

- No need for range on first part, you can simply use `[89]`
- BASH Shell's regex engine doesn't support `\d` therefore you need to use character class `[0-9]`

Comment: You're welcome, test it out and let me know if it doesn't work for any chance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for:

```
^[89]\d{7}
```

The logic of your regex is the above one, and the solution goes to be:

```
^[89][[:digit:]]{7}
```

Comment: @revo I guess that you need to say `[[:digit:]]`, not `[:digit:]`.

Comment: You forgot the `$` at the end.